# How to get MAPI's IMessage interface definition in C#

Tags: c#, interface, interop, pinvoke, mapi

For instance, at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455823/Managed-MAPI-Part-1-Logon-MAPI-Session-and-Retriev they have IMAPISession definition (although I have no idea if they used any tool to generate it).

I was not able to find a similar definition (with all methods) for IMessage interface anywhere on the Internet.

Looks like I cannot just describe the methods I'm interested in because the order of methods in the interface definition matters and if the method I need (for instance, GetRecipientTable) is not the first in the method map, I need to specify all its predecessors. Maybe if I knew DispIDs of the methods, I would be able to workaround that but I don't know how to get these DispIDs (and even if this would help or not). Currently, I was able to successfully use a couple of method like GetLastError which reside in the beginning of the interface table but if I try to use a method like GetRecipientTable (which resides at 20th position or something like that, I'm getting "Unknown error" exceptions in Outlook.

Initially, I wasn't able to use SaveChanges method (#2 in the interface map) but after I added GetLastError (#1) before it, SaveChanges started working. I also noticed it doesn't matter how SaveChanges is named, I can rename it and it keeps working. This confirmed my assumptions that it's the position in interface definition, not the name, what actually matters.

My current definition looks like:

```
[
  ComImport, ComVisible(false),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
  Guid("00020307-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
]
public interface IMessage
{
    int GetLastError(int hResult, uint ulFlags, out IntPtr lppMAPIError); // Works
    int SaveChanges(uint ulFlags); // Works (after adding GetLastError)
    // More entries need to be added here
    int GetRecipientTable(uint ulFlags, out IntPtr lppTable); // Crashes
};
```

I think I can manually make them all by analyzing parameters of all the methods in IMessage interface in MSDN but it will take a lot of time and going to be quite boring. Maybe there is more elegant solution for that or just someone can point me at already existing IMessage interface map in C#.

Comment: The friendly kind of COM interfaces are declared in a type library.  Very similar to .NET metadata and directly usable in a .NET project.  These interfaces are not friendly whatsoever, made with the assumption that client code was going to be written in C++.  No dispids, these are not an IDispatch interfaces.  Using the .h files is possible in .NET as well, you'd have to create a C++/CLI class library project.   Best way to do it.  Your IMessage declaration is missing 13 methods, being off by one is likely to cause a crash.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it indeed works. The solution looks like far from elegant but at least it works.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My high-level task was to fix MeetingResponseStatus for attendees. This is not doable via OOM so I have to go to Extended MAPI level for that.

Comment: Is using Redemption an option? It wraps Extended MAPI and is accessible from C#.

Comment: My intention is to avoid using any COM dependencies (and native C++ wrappers, like MAPIEx), only C# code.